# Migrate between GlassFish and Wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, wildfly, wildfly-10

Actually i have a web application create with JEE and i use **`Glassfish`**, now i want to change the application server, i want to migrate to **[Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/)**.

My question is :

> Is there many changes i should to do it in my application to be adapted to **`Wildfly`** Server, or not, if yes, what should i put in mind to make this migration?

**N.B**

My application is not small application, it is a big one, and it run many societies, so i put in my head that the migration can make many problems.

Thank you.

Comment: I work for Payara, so feel free to entirely ignore this, but...have you considered Payara Server? :-) It's derived from GlassFish so a potentially complex migration would likely be much easier that moving to WildFly, where many of the API implementations are different (e.g. moving from EclipseLink to Hibernate)

Comment: To help us answer your actual question though, what version of GlassFish are you coming from and what version of WildFly are you targeting?

Comment: In addition to what @Mike said, when you say you have a big application, can you go into more detail?  When I ported from Glassfish to Wildfly there weren't too many issues but we didn't have anything custom like realms and so on.

Comment: Thank you @Mike actually we use `Payara`  and we really migrate our application to `Payara`, it really work fine and there are big difference between `GlassFish` and `Payara` for example `Payara` is so quick then the `Glassfish`, now we just try to test `Wildfly`, in the end we will use one of them, but for me `Payara`  is really good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check out [this](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/) guide for a basic knowledge about what is needed to be configured. The change should be similar for Wildfly 8 and 10

Comment: Thank you @Quincy this can help me :)